# Load XML file with Ajax [Object Oriented]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

This is an example of my xml file, with `<studentenhuizen>` repeated multiple times:

```
<studentenhuis>
  <studentenhuizen>
    <adres>Aalbeeksesteenweg</adres>
    <huisnr>19</huisnr>
    <gemeente>KORTRIJK</gemeente>
    <aantal_kamers>14</aantal_kamers>
  </studentenhuizen>
</studentenhuis>
```

My object

```
function StudentenKot(adres, huisnr, gemeente, aantalkamers){
    this.adres = adres;
    this.gemeente = gemeente;
    this.huisnr = huisnr;
    this.aantalSlaapkamers = aantalkamers;
};
```

Load xml file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    url:url,
    success: function (xml) {
        studentenhuis = new Array();
        $(xml).find("studentenhuizen").each(function () {
            studentenhuis.push(new StudentenKot(this.adres, this.huisnr, this.gemeente, this.aantal_kamers));
        });

        $.each(studentenhuis, function (i) {
            $(".studentenkoten").append("<div class='gemeente'>" + studentenhuis[i].adres + "</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

When added to the `<div class="gemeente">` it says "undefined".
This worked before, but it says [Object object] now

```
alert($(xml).find("adres"));
```

Comment: What do you `this.adres, this.huisnr, …` expect to be in that `each` loop? `this` is an XML node, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah it is, I confused it with json haven't I? Either way 'adres = $(xml).find("adres")' --> alert(adres) won't work either.

Comment: Try `console.log(studentenhuis[i])` in your last `each` loop to see the structure of it. Chances are you're just missing a key identifier or something trivial like that

Comment: It says: `aantalSlaapkamers: undefined
adres: undefined
gemeente: undefined
huisnr: undefined
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this.adres` - I confused it with json haven't I?

Yes, you have. This should've said `undefined` when alerting/stringifying it.

> `$(xml).find("adres")` - it says [Object object] now

Yes, what `find` returns is a jQuery collection object which will get stringified to `"[object Object]"`. You want:

- not the `<adres>` node (nor a jQuery collection with it), but its text content
- to search the current `<studentenhuizen>` node, not the whole `xml`.

So use

```
$(xml).find("studentenhuizen").each(function () {
    studentenhuis.push(new StudentenKot(
        $(this).find("adres").text(),
        $(this).find("huisnr").text(),
        $(this).find("gemeente").text(),
        $(this).find("aantal_kamers").text()
     ));
});
```

Comment: Didn't know that jQuery can wrap XML, too. :)

Comment: @Peter: Wrapping is no problem, only some html-specific methods (`.html()`, `offset()`, `animate()` etc) might not work. However, the way jQuery does *parse* HTML was not designed to work with XML, so there are lots of cross-browser problems with this [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjquery%5d%20%5bxml%5d%20parse). I personally wouldn't use it, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Okay, there are seem to be pretty many issues with this kind of approach. Haven't tried this one : http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/ yet, but it looks pretty complete.